# Jquery resize dynamic update?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my window resize to work but I have to update the page every time to get it to work. Is there any way that this can update dynamic??

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);

  function checkWidth() {
    var window_size = $window.width();
    if(window_size> 1820){
      $('.22').addClass('size33');
      $('.22').removeClass('size22');
    } else {
      $('.22').removeClass('size33');
      $('.22').addClass('size22');
    }
  }

  // Execute on load
  checkWidth();

  // Bind event listener
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? I tried your code and the event runs perfectly fine on resizing

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.body.selectElementbyId("div id")
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var window_size = $window.width();

        if(window_size> 1820){
           $('.22').addClass('size33');
           $('.22').removeClass('size22');
        } else {
           $('.22').removeClass('size33');
           $('.22').addClass('size22');
        }
        document.getElementbyId("div id").style.width = window_size;
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: great, i have a plug-in that not working when i apply this, is there any way that i can execute the plug in in the function

Comment: put the code on jsfiddle and i will help you. which type of a plugin is it?